# Hyperlink to value

Tags: xslt

I have a form generated form the xml using xsl and it has a column called 'ref' with some value. now i want to have a  link to the ref value using XSL and when clicking the link should take to the some other node. Below is the code im using to get the value

```
<div class="r-d-form-d">
    <label class="r-d-form-d-label" for="ip-txt-{position()}-{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="ip-txt-{position()}-{name()}" id="ip-txt-{position()}-{name()}" size="50" maxlength="200" value="{.}" class="text r-d-form-d-ip glow"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the link supposed to be the label? When you say link to another node, do you mean in the same document to another label? How is that 'other' node supposed to be selected, on what criteria? You have already created a label with a dynamic name, you just have to do the same for an `<a>` tag with its `href` attribute. Which is the part that you are missing?

Comment: Linke to the value of a Lable - e.g. ref - 12345 (here 12345 suld be a link). and yes the link points to the same document.

Comment: So, you have a label `<label>12345</label>`, and 12345 should be a link,  so `<label><a href="#some_id_inside_the_doc">12345</a></label>`. To which id do you want the link to be to?

Comment: <label>ref</label> <textfield>12345</textfield> and i want link to the value in the text field. the below code is fetching the value 12345.                                                                                                                                                                                                               <input type="text" name="ip-txt-{position()}-{name()}" id="ip-txt-{position()}-{name()}" size="50" maxlength="200" value="{.}" class="text r-d-form-d-ip glow"/>

Comment: So `<label><a href="#ip-txt-{position()}-{name()}">ref</a></label>` ? You have already generated a unique id for the text field, you just refer to it. If these two are **not** in the same node, then you need to also supply the xslt between those elements.

Comment: how to get the attribute value of element node. say i waht to access the value of ref attribute and its an attribute of element node..                                                                      <element level="1" location="11" name="$20-Copay-per-Visit IN Level-1 - ChoiceNet Tier 1" networkType="IN" ref="CP0100301005" type="CoPay" version="A.2"/>

Comment: To access an attribute, use the `@` operator : `<label><a href="#{@ref}"></a></label>`

Comment: actually, the <element tag> which i put is a self closing node. how to access the value of attribute inside it

Comment: below is the code im using to get the value but not working.              <xsl:template match="ns1:element[ns1:element[@ref]]">

  <xsl:element name="element">
      <xsl:attribute name="ref">
        <label class="r-d-form-d-label" for="ip-txt-{position()}-{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="@ref"/></label>
    <input type="text" name="ip-txt-{position()}-{name()}" id="ip-txt-{position()}-{name()}" size="50" maxlength="200" value="{.}" class="text r-d-form-d-ip glow"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
     </xsl:element>
      
     </xsl:template>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This below works in some way, but I am still not sure what you are trying to accomplish.

```
<xsl:template match="ns1:element[ns1:element[@ref]]"> 
    <div>
    <label class="r-d-form-d-label" for="ip-txt-{position()}-{name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="ns1:element/@ref"/>
    </label> 
    <input type="text" name="ip-txt-{position()}-{name()}" id="ip-txt-{position()}-{name()}" size="50" maxlength="200" value="{ns1:element/@ref}" class="text r-d-form-d-ip glow"/> 
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

I hope this puts you in the right way. Good luck.